# Rank and Nullity of Projection of Multivectors onto k-Blades

Tags: linear-algebra, geometric-algebras

> Describe the image and kernel of the projection function & verify the rank-nullity theorem:
>
> The projection function is defined as $P_B(M) = {(M \cdot B)}\ /\ B$ where **M** is a multivector in $GA^n$ and **B** is a k-blade.

My work so far:
So the image is just $\mathrm {Im}(P_B) = \{{(M \cdot B)}\ /\ B\ |\ M \mathrm {\ is\ a\ multivector\ in\ GA^n\ and}\ B \mathrm {\ is\ a\ blade}\}$. $\ $I can't figure out any way to simplify that.
The kernel is $K(P_B) = \{M\ | \ {(M \cdot B)}\ /\ B = 0\} = \{M\ |\ (M \cdot B) = 0\}$. $\ $
I don't know how else to describe these.

Then the rank-nullity theorem is about their dimensions.  The dimension of the kernel would be at most n - grade($B$) because all $M \cdot B \neq 0$ are in the subspace of $R^n$ represented by $B$ which is grade($B$)-dimensional. (I'm using left contraction for the dot product.)

I'm not sure how to figure out exactly what the dimension of the kernel or image is though.

Comment: If A is a j-blade.  Then the projection of A onto B is $(A \cdot B)\ /\ B$.  Assuming B is nonzero, this will equal zero iff the subspace represented by A is NOT a subset of the subspace represented by B.  This comes from the theorem that $(A \cdot B) = 0$ iff there is some $a_i$ in A s.t. $a_i$ is orthogonal to B.  Thus the kernel must be at most n - grade(B) as I said earlier.  But when we use a general multivector M instead of j-blade A, I don't think it's this simple, because EVERY blade in M must contain a vector orthogonal to B.  So how to find the dimension?  Anyone?

Comment: This is *Linear and Geometric Algebra*?  So you're not expected to use calculus here?

Comment: That's right.  It's problem 8.1.12 in case you'd like to look it up.

Comment: I don't really care if you give me an answer using calculus, but I'd guess that it's not strictly required since MacDonald doesn't assume calculus in the book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Macdonald doesn't go far enough in describing the kernel and image, I think.  It's known from vanilla linear algebra that the kernel and image are subspaces; using geometric algebra, we can say that **the kernel and image are blades**, since we can use blades to represent subspaces.

So what we really want to do is take the pseudoscalar $i$ ($n$-blade) and *factor* it into two blades $i = KI$, where $K$ is the kernel, and $P(I)$ is the image.

It's hard to do this systematically; most of the literature for finding the kernel of a linear map focuses on row reduction of a matrix, a specifically coordinate-based solution.  I think Macdonald intended you to look at this problem geometrically:  this is a *projection* onto $B$, so the kernel is naturally the orthogonal complement of $B$, that is, $iB$.  Similarly, the projection forces all vectors into $B$ (or to zero), so the image is $B$.

But, this is one of those problems where the solution is so obvious on the one hand that I'm having a hard time figuring out a good and valid proof for it.  I suspect one would start from the top down:  first, see if $P(i)$ is nonzero.  If it is nonzero, then there is no kernel, and the image is $i$.  If it is zero, then look at all combinations of $n-1$-blades.  If there is a nonzero combination, then there is a common vector underlying all combinations that do yield zero.

You'll notice that the factorization $i = KI$ implicitly gives us the rank-nullity theorem, as the grades of $K$ and $I$ must add to the grade of $i$ (which is $n$), and linear maps are grade-preserving.

Comment: Muphrid is right: I intend the reader to look at this problem geometrically. I will add a note to this effect to the errata file sometime this coming week.\\ Note the spelling of my last name.